# How to use break statement in an Array method such as filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to solve an algorithm challenge which required;

> Drop the elements of an array (first argument), starting from the
>   front, until the predicate (second argument) returns true.
>
> The second argument, func, is a function you'll use to test the first
>   elements of the array to decide if you should drop it or not.
>
> Return the rest of the array, otherwise return an empty array.

Though I have been able to come up with a lengthy solution to this through looping the array I was wondering if there is a way to implement the break statement inside the methods.

Could it be accomplish by redefining the Array.prototype.filter method to accept a break statement ?

Though the solution could have been easy as such the methods of arrays in JavaScript doesn't accept this. How do you bypass that?

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.filter(func);
}
```

Comment: Breaking filter doesn't make sense if you think what filter does and how it works. Maybe every/some?

Comment: This is totally about `.findIndex()` and `.slice()`. You have to do like `arr.slice(arr.findIndex(condition))`

Answer (score 10):

You can just use `for` loop and when function returns true you can just break loop and return results from that index.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function drop(data, func) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var check = func(data[i]);
    if (check) {
      result = data.slice(i);
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var result = drop(arr, e => e == 4)

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `findIndex()` and if match is found you can slice array from that index otherwise return empty array.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7, 8];

var index = arr.findIndex(e => e == 4)
var result = index != -1 ? arr.slice(index) : []

console.log(result)
```