# How to limit for 10 results the array.filter?

Tags: javascript

I have big array, I want to make an autocomplete search, but I want to display only 10 results, so stop iterating through the array by the time there were found 10 results. I have made this:

```
let items = array.filter(r => r.indexOf(term)!=-1);
console.log(items.length) // lots of items, need to be limited to 10
```

It works but I don't know how to stop the `array.filter` by the time it reaches the desired limit.

Comment: `items.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: But it slices AFTER it iterated through all of the origin array.

Comment: `[1,2,3].filter((r, i) => i < 2)` would be one, slighly inefficient way of doing it, but all items in the array will be processed. Otherwise, just roll your own.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356295/how-to-use-break-statement-in-an-array-method-such-as-filter

Comment: @Raz yeah you are right, so I added an answer with a generator function instead :)

Comment: Isn't at this point an ordinary loop faster and shorter than almost any of the answers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use another variable to keep track of how many items matched the condition so far and always return false after the limit has been reached. Here is an example:

```js
const arr = [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
const filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
  if (this.count < 10 && item > 0) {
    this.count++;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}, {count: 0});

console.log(filtered);
```

Here, I'm using an object `{count: 0}` as the context of the callback function. You can find out more about [`Array.filter` from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Smart. I keep forgetting about the second parameter in `.filter` (and `.map`, etc).

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, it is there but I don't use it that much because it requires a normal function, it doesn't work with arrow functions.

Comment: @spender when you pass a second parameter to `.filter` - in this case `{count: 0}`, it will be used as `this` for the callback you pass as first parameter. It's probably a good idea for the answer to mention it - it's quite rare that it's used, so it's a bit obscure.

Comment: I've never seen that before. Interesting, but really the `count` isn't necessary, because `filter` hands you a count as the second parameter of its callback. `arr.filter(function(item, index){...`

Comment: @spender The second parameter is the index of the current item in the original array not the array that is being created.

Comment: @spender it's not a count, it's *the index*. If your condition has `index < 10` then you would only filter the first `10` elements.

Comment: This will still loop over every element

Comment: @VLAZ You're right. I really should wake up a bit more before wading into these sorts of things :)

Comment: not good enough, because the function will be called `array.length - 1` times anyway, even if the limit is `10` it doesn't make sense, the iteration must stop at 10.

Answer (score 10):

Basically you can use a generator function, which can be stopped by a self made limit, like in the below function

```js
function *filter(array, condition, maxSize) {
  if (!maxSize || maxSize > array.length) {
    maxSize = array.length;
  }
  let count = 0;
  let i = 0;
  while ( count< maxSize && i < array.length ) {
    if (condition(array[i])) {
      yield array[i];
      count++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log( Array.from( filter(array, i => i % 2 === 0, 2 ) ) ); // expect 2 & 4
```

So it will stop after it reaches maxSize as a parameter, and to easily return it into an array, you can use Array.from, which will iterate the iterator of the generator function

Comment: This is the solution I'd go for. Nowdays, you can shorthand `Array.from(someIterable)` with a spread: `[...someIterable]`

Comment: @spender that's a good point, I don't mind the shorthand syntax, but I like being explicit :)

Comment: What's the benefit of using a generator over the following? (sorry for the formatting)
`function filter2(array, condition, maxSize) {
  if (!maxSize || maxSize > array.length) maxSize = array.length

  let count = 0
  let index = 0
  let filtered = []

  while (count < maxSize) {
    if (condition(array[index])) {
      filtered.push(array[index])
      count++
    }
    index++
  }
  
  return filtered
}`

Comment: The benefits are that you don't need to create an extra array and you are getting a stream of the filtered result.

Answer (score 8):

You could hand over a counter and omit any other values for filtering.

```js
const
    filter = v => v % 2,
    filterMax = (fn, c) => x => c && fn(x) && c--,
    max = 3,
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    result = array.filter(filterMax(filter, max));

console.log(result);
```

Taking the idea of Icepickle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168992/1447675) a bit ahead with a loop for finding the next valid item and yield this one.

```js
function* filterMax(array, cb, count) {
    var i = 0;
    while (count) {
        while (i < array.length && !cb(array[i])) i++;
        if (i >= array.length) return;
        yield array[i++];
        count--;
    }
}

const
    filter = v => v % 2,
    max = 3,
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(...filterMax(array, filter, max));
```

Comment: Can I ask why you didn't use `array.filter(...).slice(0,max)`?

Comment: @MaheerAli that would go through THE ENTIRE ARRAY. If you have 1 million items and filter them down to 900 thousand, only to take the first 10, that's a huge waste of processing power.

Comment: This will also go through the entire array

Comment: @VLAZ This code also goes through all the elements of array the code doesn't break even if the result becomes greater than `max`

Comment: @MaheerAli but it doesn't run the predicate against each item. That's where the majority of the computation would come from - simply iterating the array without doing anything would have negligible performance hit. EDIT: if you want to experiment: `arr = Array.from({length: 1000000}, (_, i) => i); arr.filter(() => false)`

Answer (score 6):

You can't `break` from `Array.prototype.filter` method. It will loop over every element. You can use a simple `for` loop and break when 10 items are found

```
const items = []
for (const value of array) {
  if (value.includes(term))
    items.push(value)
  if (items.length === 10)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Question specificly asks for filter but this would be the best approach otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the trick :

**EDIT :** To clarify this code will pick the 10 first even number of the list

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];

const result = array.reduce((temp, value) => {
  if(value%2==0 && temp.length<10)
    temp.push(value);
  return temp;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note that it is not the most efficient way to do, you should better do a classic for loop then break it as soon as your cond is true

Comment: But this keep iterating the whole array, just ignoring the uneven numbers.

Comment: @Raz yes that's why I said it is not the way i would do. It was just for to show a "tricky" usage of reduce.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]

var limited = data.filter((val,i)=>i<10)
console.log(limited)
```

Comment: @spender you are talking about `i<10` one?

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. If there is another condition in filter, it would break. If you have a condition lie this, `data.filter((val,i)=> val>5 && i<10)`. it would return only 5 values, as the index of '11' is 10 and the second condition fails.

Answer (score 2):

[I wrote a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) that's handy for this sort of thing.

Here's how I'd find the first 100 numbers that start with the character "1"

```js
const {blinq, range} = window.blinq;

//create a large array of strings to search
const arrToBeSearched = range(0,10000)
  .select(x => `${x}`)
  .toArray()

const query = blinq(arrToBeSearched)
  .where(x => x.startsWith("1"))
  .takeWhile((x, i) => i < 100)

const result = [...query] //no calculation until we materialize on this line

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just simple add `.Slice(0,NO_OF_ELE_WANT)`
eg. finding first two even no

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].filter((e)=> e%2==0).slice(0,2)
```

Answer : `let items = array.filter(r => r.indexOf(term)!=-1).slice(0,10);`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but here's one for the newcomers!

```js
// we'll create a function which will take two arguments
// first argument would be your original array which you want to filter from
// second argument would be the number of results you want the filter to return

const limitedArray = (originalArray, limit) => {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let item of originalArray) {
      if (newArray.length >= limit) break;
      //your code here
      //in my case i'll jush push onto the array
      newArray.push(item)
    }
    return newArray;
  };
  
//---------------->ignore v<-------------------  

//the above function would return an array so in other words we can see this function as an array
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cascas', 'ascasc', 9, 10, 'ascs'];

console.log(limitedArray(array, 4));
//similarly
limitedArray(array, 4).forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom method on `Array.prototype` which will take 2 arguments. A callback and a max elements that result array will contain.

The code below gets the first 3 odd numbers from array.

```js
function filterUpto(callback,max){
  let len = this.length
  let res = [];
  let i = 0;
  while(res.length < max && i < len){
    if(callback(this[i],i,this)) res.push(arr[i])
    i++
  }
  return res;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'filterUpto',{
  value:filterUpto
})

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(arr.filterUpto(x => x % 2,3)); //first three odd numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution, pretty straightforward, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const arr = [
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "foobar",
  "baz",
  "foobaz",
  "artefact",
  "mortar",
  "bar",
  "arity",
  "mark",
  "car",
  "dare",
  "arbitrary",
  "tar",
  "jar",
  "war",
];

const filterWithLimit = (arr, value, length) =>
  Array.from(
    { length },
    function () {
      return arr
        .slice(this.index++)
        .find((option, i) => (this.index += i, option.includes(value)));
    },
    { index: 0 }
  );

console.log(filterWithLimit(arr, "ar", 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution which doesn't continue searching after the limit is reached:

```js
function filter_n(array, limit, test) {
   let ret = []
   array.find((x)=> test(x) && ret.push(x)>=limit )
   return ret
}
```

- when `test(x)` is true, it calls `ret.push(x)` (which adds `x` to `ret` and *outputs the length of `ret`*)

  - then, once `ret`'s length is >= `limit`, the inner function returns true, and `find` stops looping because it "found" a result

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Titus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56169001/5397888), I have adapted it for my purposes so that it no longer continues to filter after the limit is reached:

```js
const old_arr = [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
const max_len = 5;

const new_arr = old_arr.filter(function (item, index, a) {
  if (item % 2 === 0) { // replace with actual filter condition
    this.count++;
    if (this.count >= max_len) {
      a.splice(index);
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}, { count: 0 });
```