# Find first several elements in an array that meet a condition, using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got an array (rather large: tens of thousands of elements) and I need to find the first `n` elements that meet a condition, where `n` may vary but is small compared to the array size (typically smaller than 5).  I realize I can do

```
    array.filter(meetsCondition).slice(0,n)
```

which is readable and concise, but that `.filter` is iterating the entire array so it's not very efficient.  I'd rather stop iterating when I've found the `n`th element, just like `.find` does for 1 element.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
    function findSome(array, n) {
      var matches = [];
      var i=0;
      while (matches.length < n) {
        // Check if we ran out of elements.
        if (i >= array.length) return null; // Could also return a shorter list; I'm indifferent.
        if (meetsCondition(array[i]) matches.push(array[i]);
        i++;
      } 
      return matches;
    }
```

which accomplishes the goal, but it's not as readable.  So my question is: Is there is a built-in method or more concise way to accomplish this, that also stops iterating when `n` elements are found?

In this use case I can't leverage any tools other than pure Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168771/how-to-limit-for-10-results-the-array-filter

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the loop by checking the length and inside if met the condition check the length after pushing for breaking.

```
function findSome(array, n) {
    var matches = [],
        i = 0,
        l = array.length;

    while (i < l) {
        if (meetsCondition(array[i]) && matches.push(array[i]) === n) break;
        i++;
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for` loop with `break` statement

```js
const n = 3
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

const meetsCondition = (num) => num % 2 === 0

const findSome = (array, n) => {
  const res = []

  for (const element of array) {
    console.log(element)

    if (meetsCondition(element) === true) {
      res.push(element)
    }

    if (res.length === n) {
      break
    }
  }

  return res
}

console.log("res: ", findSome(array, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a built-in function, I suggest the **Some()** function :

```
function findSome(array, n) {
var matches = [];

function check(a){

  if( a matches condition){
    matches.push(a);
  }
// if its not bigger than n it will keep on
return matches.length()<=n;

}
array.some(check(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Unfortunately my guess about .filter was wrong. I've written a small benchmark and found that .filter execution time linearly depends on the length of the array.
Code below is much faster than the .filter method

```
function filterN(arr, count, condition) {
    const result = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < arr.length && count > 0; ++index) {
        if (condition(arr[index])) {
            result.push(arr[index]);
            count--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function meetsCondition(value) { return value < 5; }
let arr = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let count = 3;
filterN(arr, count, meetsCondition);
```

You can use only filter method of Array object. I think JIT compiler should optimize the code not to iterate all elements

```
function meetsCondition(value) { return value < 5; }
let arr = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let count = 3;
let result = arr.filter((v) => meetsCondition(v) && count-- > 0);
// result is [ 4, 3, 2 ]
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference for how the compiler optimizes the code in this case?  It seems to me that it still has to check whether count>0 for the remaining elements.

Comment: Unfortunately my guess was wrong. I've written a small benchmark and found that its execution time linearly depends on the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your array into chunks:

```
function findSome(array, n) {
  let matches = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += n) {
    matches = [...matches, ...array.slice(i, i + n).filter(meetsCondition)];
    if (matches.length >= n) break;
  }

  return matches.splice(0, n);
}

const meetsCondition = e => e > 3;

console.log(findSome([1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9], 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a for loop and return when both condition and times are satisfied.

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const condition = (elem) => elem < 5;

const getFirstNElems = (list, n) => {
  let meetTimes = 0;
  const firstNElems = [];

  for (let elem of list) {
    if (condition(elem)) {
      firstNElems.push(elem);
      meetTimes += 1;
      if (meetTimes === n) {
        return firstNElems;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getFirstNElems(list, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is by using:

```
arr.some(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

Example:

```
operatives = [{ name: 'Jo'}, { name: 'Jack' }];

const operativesHasName = operatives.some((operative) => {
  return operative.name === 'Jack';
});
// => true

operativesHasName = operatives.some((operative) => {
  return operative.name === 'Jojo';
});
// => false
```

If you want to write it shorter:

```js
operatives.some((operative) => operative.name === 'Jack');
// => true

operatives.some((operative) => operative.name === 'Jojo'); 
// => false
```